# Images On My Site Are Getting Bigger

Tags: php, html, css, image

The images on my site are way WAY bigger than expected. they werent always like that though they seem to get bigger every time a make a change and upload it. One of the images look like this:

```
<div class="cbody">
<?php include("head.html");?>
<div style="float: right;">
<a href="target.php"><img src="assets/img/target.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
<a href="target2.php"><img src="assets/img/target2.jpg"></a>
</div></div>
```

and theres one that is float: left; as well. they just get bigger ;/
CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url("wallpaper.jpg");
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px 43px 0px 43px;
font-family: 'BioRhyme', serif;
}
.cbody {
background-color: gray; 
}
```

any help?

Comment: You shouldn't delete your original post ! Next generation will not understand what u r asked ? You must write that solved message as comment under answered post

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can put some size of the image that you want like on your CSS

width:50%;
  height:auto;

Comment: Welcome :) @DreninMcclures

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an exact size using css. This is done with the `width` and `height` properties.

For example:

```
<a href="target.php"><img src="assets/img/target.jpg" style="width:50px; height:25px;"></a>
```

They don't have to be in pixels, they could be percentages of the original size. e.g.

```
height:50%; width:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

is it the target images that change size? You haven't specified either in the html nor the css what size they should be:

```
<img src="assets/img/target.jpg" width="20" height="20" >
```

or in your css as @JalonJuanis said.

Comment: the images target.jpg and target2.jpg just got way huger then there supposed to be

Comment: what size in pixels are they supposed to be?